# fswatch command fires multiple events for a single move operation

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, xargs, fswatch

I have a **photos.sh** file (`osascript` set to `JavaScript`):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/osascript -l JavaScript

function run(argv) {
    return importFileIntoPhotos(argv[0])
};

// importFileIntoPhotos :: FilePath -> IO ()
const importFileIntoPhotos = fp => {
    const 
        appPhotos = Application("Photos");
    return appPhotos.import([Path(fp)])
};
```

and, the following **test.sh** file:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

fp="$HOME/Documents/Samsung T5"

fpScript="$HOME/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/VSC Files/Automation/Manuel/photos.sh"

fswatch -0 -event-flags -r --exclude=".*\.DS_Store" "$fp" | xargs -0 -n1 -r -I {} "$fpScript" "{}"
```

I execute `test.sh` in Terminal. With that process open, whenever I move a **single** photo into **fp** folder, the **same** photo is imported **multiple** times into `​Photos`​ app. Then, I have to kill the process.

How can I fix this issue, and import a **single** photo corresponding to a **single** move operation ?

**Specs**:

MacBook Air M1 with macOS Ventura

**UPDATE:**

Upon further testing, I have more clarity about the issue. Whenever the file is imported into Photos, a new event is sent (and captured) by `fswatch`, so it gets triggered again.

**UPDATE 2**:

Now, the act of importing into Photos doesn't trigger an event that could be captured by `fswatch`, and also doesn't trigger duplicated events. Not sure what happened.

**UPDATE 3**:

The issue persists. I tried opening the file in Preview app and the same is happening again. I get duplicated events. I am not sure why the act of opening that file in Preview is detected by `fswatch`.

Comment: If you're unable to get `fswatch` to work, you may be able to do this with a macOS [Folder Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html).

Comment: Thank you, @Gairfowl. Unfortunately, macOS Folder Action doesn't observe subfolders.

Comment: Your updated testing note indicates that the Photos app may be altering the metadata of a file after importing it, thus triggering the new event. Possible workarounds: turn on 'delete after import' in Photos, or have your script move or rename the file to a location ignored by `fswatch` prior to importing it.

Comment: Thank you, @Gairflow. I am not sure what happened, now the act of importing into Photos doesn't trigger an event that could be captured by `fswatch`, and also doesn't trigger duplicated events.

Comment: The issue persists. I have tried with Preview app and the same is happening again. I get duplicated events.

Comment: @Gairfowl, you were right. After all, I found the event captured by `fswatch`. Whenever I open a file in Preview, for example, one of the events captured is named `AttributeModified`.

Comment: In particular, "Date Last Opened" attribute.